# Display list of subcategories of a category page in a post - wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is the structure of my site:

Category (page from the menu) > Subcategory (list on the sidebar) > Post

The category it´s a menu item, when I enter it displays in a list of subcategories, and from that list I can enter to the post. The problem it´s that when i´m in the post I can´t list the subcategories again because if I use:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <?php the_category();?>
</ul>
```

it will display a list which only contains the current category of the post, no the similar subcategories that belongs to the global category page.

How can I do that?

Comment: Post the php file where you defined the function named the_category();

Comment: I´m using the default that wordpress use

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories).

the_category() only works within the loop and it only returns the categories which the current post object is categorized under. wp_list_categories() can be used to list the categories for your entire site or—by changing parameters to the function—categories which belong to a specific parent category or just about any list of categories you need, sorted in just about any order. Look at the documentation for the arguments to figure out which combination you need to use. It will return the categories as HTML formatted links to those categories. If you want the same information without the HTML formatting, try using [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) instead.